# Acceptable amount of logging in live environments

Tags: logging, web-applications, log4j

Having read a number of articles on logging level guidelines, including this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007720/good-guidance-for-when-to-use-which-log-level-info-warn-debug-etc-for-appli , I was wondering if there is some best practice on how much lines this should approximately produce on a live application (to make sure it's useful and not impacting performance).

Are any companies using an max target of loglines per user action, let's say per page visited on a website?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you use your log for.

If you use logs only for detecting problems, I'd set the log level to warn und expect close to zero entries.

If you use logging also for monitoring (keeping track what is used how often and how long it takes, you should probably shoot for a couple of MB per day. But you should also consider using a specialized solution like Java Melody, which probably does a better job.

This basically means: as little logging as possible ... but you should have a mechanism in place to change the log level without interupting operations, so you can get more detailed logs when needed.